# Bash add increased number to string in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have this properties file, which can have as many "spark-worker" strings in it:

```
[master]
spark-master ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-236-23-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[worker]
spark-worker ansible_ssh_host=ec2-34-204-206-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
.
.
spark-worker ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[spark_cluster:children]
master
worker
```

And I wand to add a digit after every string "spark-worker" so the result would be:

```
[master]
spark-master ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-236-23-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[worker]
spark-worker-1 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-34-204-206-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-2 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
.
.
spark-worker-n ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[spark_cluster:children]
master
worker
```

What's the best to do it bash way?

Comment: It's trivial with `awk`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with `sed`, it doesn't have any arithmetic capabilities, which would be needed to increment the number after each substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` in a `bash` script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=1 
while read -r line; do 
    sed -i.bak "s/spark-worker/&-$n/" <<< "$line"
    if [[ "$line" =~ "spark-worker" ]]; then 
        n=$(( n+1 )) 
    fi
done < input_file
```

Or as a one liner

```
$ n=1; while read -r line; do sed "s/spark-worker/&-$n/" <<< "$line"; if [[ "$line" =~ "spark-worker" ]]; then n=$(( n+1 )); fi; done < input_file
[master]
spark-master ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-236-23-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[worker]
spark-worker-1 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-34-204-206-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-2 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
.
.
spark-worker-3 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[spark_cluster:children]
master
worker
```

Or using `awk`

```
awk -v work="spark-worker" '$0~work{n++; gsub(work,work"-"n)}1' input_file
[master]
spark-master ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-236-23-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[worker]
spark-worker-1 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-34-204-206-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
spark-worker-2 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
.
.
spark-worker-3 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-3-238-204-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[spark_cluster:children]
master
worker
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but how do I make it edit the file and not just prompt it to stdout?

Comment: Running a copy of `sed` for each line in the file can get expensive if the files are big.  For small files, it won't be a problem.  I'd guess the cut-off size is somewhere in the 50-500 line range.  Personally, I'd use (one copy of) `awk`, which would be simpler and faster.  Really and truly, `sed` is not the right tool for this job — Awk, Perl, Python, … any of the power scripting languages could do the job more neatly.

Comment: @ShaharHamuzimRajuan Please check edit. Added the `-i` flag for in place edit with .bak to make a backup at the same time

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. OP asked for a `sed/bash` solution so that was initially provided. Added `awk` solution also

Comment: @HatLess You can't use `sed -i` to process strings from a variable. It can only run directly on the file, and you don't want that here since it'll apply the edit to *all* lines, not just the one currently being operating on.

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '$1 == "spark-worker" { $1 = $1 "-" ++c } 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/spark-worker/&-\n/g;T
        :a;x;s/.*/echo $((&+1))/e;x;G;s/\n(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/;/\n/ba' file
```

Turn on extended regexps by setting the `-E` command line option.

Replace all occurrences of the string `spark-worker` by a `-` and a newline.

If no substitutions took place, perform no further processing for the current line.

Otherwise, increment a counter in the hold space by way of the evaluation of the bash shell echo command, append the counter to the current line, then append that counter to the first occurrence of the required string and if there are more occurrences, repeat until there are no more.